# How to set culture to Kendo grid column?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have try to set a culture to Ireland Currency '€' to the footerTemplate. But it always set the US '$' Currency in footerTemplate.

Sample column:

```
{
      field: "IEGrantTotalAvg",
      title: "%",
      type: "number",
      filterable: false,
      format: "{0:c3}",
      attributes: { "class": "right-align" },
      footerTemplate: function (data) {
         return "<div style='white-space:initial;float:right'>" + " " + kendo.toString((Avg == null ? 0 : Avg), "c3") + "</div>";
       }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the current culture in Kendo. [See documentation here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting). Note that you will also need to include the respective culture script to the page.

I have created a [JS Fiddle](http://dojo.telerik.com/awoLo) showing currency formatting with culture en-IE in the footer template.